# Is it possible to configure Redis to automatically data replication from Server A to Server B

Tags: redis

I want to keep two instances of Redis ( server **A** and **B** ) which are installed on different hardware to keep data synchronized. When data "X" is written to server A, I want it to be synchronized to server B as well.

The reason for that is that from my client application, whenever I need to read data I can randomly pick between the two servers, **load-balancing** connection from multiple requests. This also allows to have a **high-availability** architecture so that if one server goes down the data is still on the other's cache.

How I am performing the above is through **client code** only. Whenever I write, I write to both servers ( A and B).

Is there a way to specify at server configuration level that server A will be in charge of replicating data writes to B ? Something like a trigger on any writes that replicates to server B and vice versa ( writes to server B get replicated to A ) ?

Comment: Yes. Consider reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all right here [Redis replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication)

You might instead want to implement local caching in the application, it is way faster than fetching from redis(which is in fact pretty fast too), and if you're hosting a half decent place, the uptime is like 99,9%, so availability shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: you are correct, but I might have not stated in my question that the problem is a bit more complex. I will enter another question. Overall , the issue is that my replication rule is not simply from server to another, but based on a sharding rule. Different objects "X" and "Y" might be replicated differently. An object "X" might go to server "A" and "B" and an object "Y" to servers "A" and "C". This is based on some dynamic rules. I believe this sharding replication option does not exist.

Comment: I would do that on client side. What I normally do(which I believe is good OOP practice) is to wrap the use of Redis/database inside a class. This way you only know that example `UserService.getUserByName("gextra")` gets the user, not how. So this class can implement local cache(if possible), use database or redisA or redisB server. Later you can change the design.